# what's '~' symbol means in r language script?

Tags: r

`#3-Way Frequency Table
mytable <- xtabs(~A+B+c, data=mydata)
ftable(mytable) # print table`
What's the ~ in row 2? it's not in the R operator list.

Comment: You can search by `?tilde` or `?'~'`

Comment: yes,i got it, thanks!